Spring Mongo Data returns all objects instead of DBRef id
I'm working with Spring and MongoDB. I have a Folder class which has a list of subfolders and a list of files. I'm using DBRef which stores the reference id to the list objects instead of the whole object in the database.
When I submit a get request for the "root" folder I have, the returned json also has loaded the subfolders, their subfolder, and so on. This is bad because I'm getting data I dont need right away. I would only like to get the ids of the subfolders so that if i click on one, I submit an HTTP GET with that exact id.
package org.example.schoolioapi.domain;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Document(collection = "folders")
@Data
public class Folder {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @DBRef
    private List<Folder> subFolders;
    @DBRef
    private List<Note> notes;

    public Folder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subFolders = new ArrayList<>();
        this.notes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addNote(Note note) {
        if (this.notes == null) notes = List.of(note);
        else notes.add(note);
    }

    public void addSubFolder(Folder subFolder) {
        if (this.subFolders == null) subFolders = List.of(subFolder);
        else subFolders.add(subFolder);
    }
}

Example of Folder object in DB

What the API returns:


It sounds like that you expect the response should return the 1-st level of sub-folders and their IDs, right?

@LHCHIN yes exactly

look for Mongo projection

A quick solution is to annotate subFolders with @JsonIgnoreProperties.
For example, if a Folder class looks like below:
class Folder {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("subFolders")
    private List<Folder> subFolders;

    //constructor, getters and setters
}

and we initialize the root folder as follows:
Folder root = new Folder(
    "0",
    "root",
    Arrays.asList(
        new Folder("0-1", "sub-1", Arrays.asList(
            new Folder("0-1-1", "sub-1-1", Collections.emptyList()),
            new Folder("0-1-2", "sub-1-2", Collections.emptyList())
        )),
        new Folder("0-2", "sub-2", Arrays.asList(
             new Folder("0-2-1", "sub-2-1", Collections.emptyList()),
             new Folder("0-2-2", "sub-2-2", Collections.emptyList())
        ))
    ));

then after serializing root with library Jackson, output will only contain 1-st level of subFolders:
p.s. other fields will still be serialized, need find some way to show the id only.
{
  "id" : "0",
  "name" : "root",
  "subFolders" : [ {
    "id" : "0-1",
    "name" : "sub-1"
  }, {
    "id" : "0-2",
    "name" : "sub-2"
  } ]
}


This looks great but I have a question. Will this still query ALL the subfolders and their content and just ignore them when they are returned? Because if so, if the folders have content of 10GB each this will take for ever to retrieve(if it doesnt fail at all).

Yes, this just ignores those fields annotated by @JsonIgnoreProperties while serialization. If you want to ignore some records while querying from DB, it needs other tricks.
